# Why check user again in passport.deserialzeUser function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I had read several artical about how to use passport.js.
I am wondering why they always check user again in passport.deserializeUser Function like this:

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  console.log('Inside deserializeUser callback')
  console.log(`The user id passport saved in the session file store is: ${id}`)
  const user = users[0].id === id ? users[0] : false; 
  done(null, user);
});
```

The user's credentials should already checked in login phase, and stored in sessions properly. Why they do this again ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the source code, `deserializeUser` should return a `User` object.

Therefore, the example you gave simply checks if the id stored in the session cookie matches the id of the first user in an unknown array `users` and returns this user if so.

In the [source code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/initialize.js), they give another example:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
   });
});
```

Here, this code will retrieve from a model `User` the element with value `id`. This function `deserializeUser` depends on how you serialize the user session and what data you store in the cookie.

Most likely, people will store only the user id in the cookie and then get the full information on the user by retrieving the corresponding data from a database.